# Change color of specific words or letter combinations

Tags: javascript, text, colors

I need to change the color of certain letter combinations in an element with a class.
For example: `<span class="title">ACPRO2000</span>` - in this I would want 'ACPRO' to be orange and the rest to stay the default color.

I should note that I am not adept at javascript at all.

Comment: In case you can not control the HTML, you would have to query the element via JavaScript, split the string and wrap the desired characters in another span. This way, you can style them via CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functional approach with vanilla javascript

```js
const highlightText = (text, elem, color) => {
   const element = document.querySelector( elem );
         element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replaceAll( text, `<span style="color: ${color}">${text}</span>`);
}


highlightText("ABC", '#lettersList', 'orange')
highlightText("0", '#lettersList', 'red')

highlightText("World", '#myDiv2', 'green')
```

```html
<div id="lettersList">ABC2012</div>

<div id="myDiv2">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks close to something that could work for me. I do not have control over the span class as it's part of a woocommerce product. So would it work a class and not an ID?